# R: Adress objects deep inside lists with filter commands inside functions/loops (ExtremeBounds package)

Tags: r, lapply

I am using the ExtremeBounds package which provides as a result a multi level list with (amongst others) dataframes at the lowest level. I run this package over several specifications and I would like to collect some columns of selected dataframes in these results. These should be collected by specification (spec1 and spec2 in the example below) and arranged in a list of dataframes. This list of dataframes can then be used for all kind of things, for example to export the results of different specifications into different Excel Sheets.

Here is some code which creates the problematic object (**just run this code blindly, my problem only concerns how to deal with the kind of list it creates: eba_results**):

```
library("ExtremeBounds")
Data <- data.frame(var1=rbinom(30,1,0.2),var2=rbinom(30,2,0.2),
               var3=rnorm(30),var4=rnorm(30),var5=rnorm(30))
spec1 <- list(y=c("var1"), 
             freevars=c("var2"),
             doubtvars=c("var3","var4"))
spec2 <- list(y=c("var1"), 
          freevars=c("var2"),
          doubtvars=c("var3","var4","var5"))
indicators <- c("spec1","spec2")

ebaFun <- function(x){
eba  <- eba(data=Data, y=x$y, 
     free=x$freevars, 
     doubtful=x$doubtvars,
     reg.fun=glm, k=1, vif=7, draws=50, weights = "lri", family = binomial(logit))}

eba_results <- lapply(mget(indicators),ebaFun) #eba_results is the object in question
```

Manually I know how to access each element, for example:

```
eba_results$spec1$bounds$type #look at str(eba_results) to see the different levels
```

So "bounds" is a dataframe with identical column names for both spec1 and spec2. I would like to collect the following 5 columns from "bounds":

type, cdf.mu.normal, cdf.above.mu.normal, cdf.mu.generic, cdf.above.mu.generic

into one dataframe per spec. Manually this is simple but ugly:

```
collectedManually <-list( 
manual_spec1 = data.frame(
 type=eba_results$spec1$bounds$type, 
 cdf.mu.normal=eba_results$spec1$bounds$cdf.mu.normal,
 cdf.above.mu.normal=eba_results$spec1$bounds$cdf.above.mu.normal,
 cdf.mu.generic=eba_results$spec1$bounds$cdf.mu.generic,
 cdf.above.mu.generic=eba_results$spec1$bounds$cdf.above.mu.generic),
manual_spec2= data.frame(
 type=eba_results$spec2$bounds$type, 
 cdf.mu.normal=eba_results$spec2$bounds$cdf.mu.normal,
 cdf.above.mu.normal=eba_results$spec2$bounds$cdf.above.mu.normal,
 cdf.mu.generic=eba_results$spec2$bounds$cdf.mu.generic,
 cdf.above.mu.generic=eba_results$spec2$bounds$cdf.above.mu.generic))
```

But I have more than 2 specifications and I think this should be possible with lapply functions in a prettier way. Any help would be appreciated!

*p.s.: A generic example to which hrbrmstr's answer applies but which turned out to be too simplistic:*

```
exampleList = list(a=list(aa=data.frame(A=rnorm(10),B=rnorm(10)),bb=data.frame(A=rnorm(10),B=rnorm(10))),
               b=list(aa=data.frame(A=rnorm(10),B=rnorm(10)),bb=data.frame(A=rnorm(10),B=rnorm(10))))
```

*and I want to have an object which collects, for example, all the A and B vectors into two data frames (each with its respective A and B) which are then a list of data frames. Manually this would look like:*

```
dfa <- data.frame(A=exampleList$a$aa$A,B=exampleList$a$aa$B)
dfb <- data.frame(A=exampleList$a$aa$A,B=exampleList$a$aa$B)
collectedResults <- list(a=dfa, b=dfb)
```

Comment: What is your desired output out all of this?

Comment: a list of data frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a brute force way which works but is dependent on several named objects:

```
collectEBA <- function(x){
 df <- paste0("eba_results$",x,"$bounds")
 df <- eval(parse(text=df))[,c("type",
                            "cdf.mu.normal","cdf.above.mu.normal",
                            "cdf.mu.generic","cdf.above.mu.generic")]
 df[is.na(df)] <- "NA"
 df
 }
eba_export <- lapply(indicators,collectEBA)
names(eba_export) <- indicators
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a less brute-force way to do this.

If you want lists of individual columns this is one way:

```
get_col <- function(my_list, col_name) {
  unlist(lapply(my_list, function(x) {
    lapply(x, function(y) { y[, col_name] })
  }), recursive=FALSE)
}

get_col(exampleList, "A")
get_col(exampleList, "B")
```

If you want a consolidated data.frame of indicator columns this is one way:

```
collect_indicators <- function(my_list, indicators) {
  lapply(my_list, function(x) {
    do.call(rbind, c(lapply(x, function(y) { y[, indicators] }), make.row.names=FALSE))
  })[[1]]
}

collect_indicators(exampleList, c("A", "B"))
```

If you just want to bring the individual data.frames up a level to make it easier to iterate over to write to a file:

```
unlist(exampleList, recursive=FALSE)
```

Much assumption about the true output format is being made (the question was a bit vague).

Comment: could you explain the nested lapply's? I'm getting a bit lost there... I updated the question

Comment: the first one iterates across the first level in the list and passes each sub-list to the next lappy iterator. that iterator works on the individual level 2 sublists. by default it returns a nested list structure (each `lapply` returns a list) so we have to unlist only the top-most level to unravel that structure.

Comment: so if I have more levels of lists, I need more levels of lapply?

Comment: perhaps. without seeing the structures and knowing the full problem trying to be solved it's hard to generalize any recommendation.

Comment: sorry for that, I really thought the problem is simpler than that... I updated the list in the question to have one more level

Comment: I edited the question with an example that creates the list of the actual problem. Does this help? I'll clean up the question if we get somewhere. Or should I write a new one?

Comment: i may have a bit of time later today (work-work beckons)

Comment: ok, thanks! I'll clean up the question in the meantime and keep the original one in p.s. so your answer still applies for now.

Comment: done, don't be put off by the long code please, you just have to run that to get the messy list that I'm struggling with and an example of where I want to get in the end. All I need is how to get from the list `eba_results` to my `collectedManually` without, well, collecting manually ;-)